# Authentication token to be logged forever

Tags: security, authentication, access-token

In Facebook app or twitter, I am logged forever(a very big period of time).

I heard that to have 1 token for forever login is not ok from security point of view.

How that applications can login a user for a very big period of time and and do not have problems with security?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs to [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).